# how to visualize samples from posterior probability density function?

Tags: bayesian, data-visualization

I am doing Bayesian parameter estimation/regression and I have formulated the posterior p.d.f. and is able to sample from it. Except of credibility intervals around MAP (as a gray zone around solid line), I don't know what other appropriate plots I can show and what it may mean.

Can I get help please. I am using MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at 1 parameter you can show a density estimate (this will be nice especially if it is a multi-modal or skewed distribution). For 2 parameters you can look at perspective plots or contour plots to get a similar idea.

For more than 2 parameters it gets a bit tricky. Summary statistics like MAP, posterior quantiles, posterior mean could be helpful.